# How to use mockups in Gimp

Tags: gimp, perspective, mockup

I am all new to Gimp, so this may be a very basic question. I want to use a mockup that I found online to put my images in a picture frame. Now, I can only do this by adding the image as a layer and then resize it until it fits. Very cumbersome to do this with 100 images..

Can I simply paste my image in the pre-made layer? And how? Don't know if it matters, but the image and picture frame are in perspective.

I have been struggling with this for hours now and could not find the answer myself. Hope someone can help!

Comment: GIMP doesn't have that functionality.  It's something that's done in Photoshop using Smart Objects, which GIMP doesn't support currently.  In GIMP, the image would need to be resized/distorted for perspective manually.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Too bad I can't do it in GIMP..